# Integral as a function of the upper limit in matlab

Tags: graphing-functions, matlab

How to plot a function like $f(x) = \int_0^x\sqrt{t^2sin(t)}dt ,  x ∈ [0 , 10]$ in matlab (or gnuplot)?

Comment: For values of $x>\pi$, the integral will return complex values. Are you interested in the complex solutions?

Comment: This integral is just an example. I mean $ f(x) = \int_a^xg(t)dt , x ∈ [a,b]$

Comment: Use [`integral`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html) and [`plot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html). See documentation for more. This seems like it's more of a programming question than a math one and thus might be off-topic for this site. [StackOverflow.com/matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab) might be a better venue, but you should first make an attempt yourself and ask a specific question with code.